# plot in node.js

Tags: node.js, matplotlib, gnuplot

I would like to build a server using node.js which is able to plot graphs.

I could not find useful information so far on how to hook Matplotlib/ Pylab into node.

Maybe GNUPlot can be hooked up? I personally prefer Matplotlib but GNUPlot would be fine, too. In my experience the tools I mentioned outperform tools like flot or TheJit for huge data loads.

Any suggestions on creating fast plots from within node.js will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Either use child processes and [execute external programs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.4/api/all.html#child_process.exec), watch for theit termination and take the output. Or have a look at the [node-canvas](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas) lib if you want to do it by yourself.

Comment: I do not think this is a good idea. As I stated performance matters! If there is no direct integration possible I consider to link the tools via 0MQ way superior.

Comment: Node.js is good for large scale, parallel I/O, and not for complex computations. If you need the node application as a wrapper that provdes i.e. the graph generation as a web service, than pool the external processes and this might work well. If don't, node.js might be the wrong choice. Unfortunately, you haven't told us much about your node application in general.